# Code Editor not recognizes Russian characters

Tags: delphi, non-ascii-characters, delphi-10.3-rio, code-editor

I'm trying to translate some parts of a [project example](http://alexander-bagel.blogspot.com/2016/03/early-execution.html) where all comment parts and console output are in the Russian language, but when the project is opened via IDE, seems that Code Editor does not recognize this language, example:

[image]

Then, exists some setting into IDE (or any other trick) that can solve it (also to any language, not only Russian)?

Thank you.

Comment: Use UTF-8 as the source code encoding. That will work just fine. I always use a lot of "strange" characters in my source files (mathematical operators etc. in string literals). [But getting the characters to display properly in the console window is a different thing.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Delphi code editor supports non-ASCII (and non-ANSI) characters. Just make sure to use the UTF-8 encoding for the source code.

[image: Screenshot of the Delphi source code editor with Persian text and mathematical operators.]

If you enter non-ANSI characters in a previously non-UTF file and try to save, the IDE will ask you if you want to change the encoding to UTF8:

[image: Screenshot of dialog box asking the user if (s)he want to change the encoding to UTF8.]

In any case, you can use the editor's context menu to set the encoding:

[image: Screenshot of the code editor's context menu, with the "File Format" submenu open. It contains various kinds of text encodings, such as ANSI and UTF8.]

However, the code editor is -- unfortunately -- somewhat buggy when you use non-ANSI characters. For instance, consider the following line of code:

[image: A line of code in the Delphi IDE's editor. It contains Persian and mathematical characters, and ends with a call to the Exit procedure. The caret is within the word "Exit".]

If I press Ctrl+W at this point, I expect the word "Exit" to become selected, because that's what Ctrl+W is supposed to do. But the "strange" characters on the line makes the editor all confused, and this is what happens:

[image: A part of the line to the left of "Exit" has become selected.]

Here is the line as plain text:

```
ShowMessage('ریاضیات: (∂/∂t) ∫ sin(xt) dt'); Exit;
```

Comment: (This is a bug that really annoys me. I have many files with many string literals containing mathematical operators (automated tests for a mathematical system), and Ctrl+W is one of my favourite shortcuts that I use all the time.)

Comment: When i set to UTF-8 nothing happens, not is working, still with strange characters on Code Editor after open project again (even after **Save** when is set to UTF-8).

Comment: @BrowJr You need to open your .pas files in Notepad++, convert encoding from Windows-1251 to UTF-8 (Encoding - Convert to UTF8), save it and only then open they in Delphi.